How to get more data from RSS Feed?
I created an react native expo app which can fetch and show rss feed data
Suppose on this site https://www.drive.com.au/news/ there are almost 30 posts and show more option but when I fetch the rss feed using this link https://www.drive.com.au/feed/ I got only 10 items. Why I'm not getting all the posts and is there any way to get more posts ?
My function looks like this :
// Function to fetch RSS Feed
const fetchRSSFeed = async (
  url: string,
  setFeedData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<FeedItem[]>>,
  setLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
) => {
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const parser = new xml2js.Parser();

    parser.parseString(response.data, (err: any, result: any) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error parsing XML:", err);
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }

      const items: FeedItem[] = result?.rss?.channel[0]?.item || [];
      setFeedData((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...items]); // Add new feed items to the list
      setLoading(false);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching RSS feed:", error);
    setLoading(false);
  }
};


I tried to look for pagination information on the rss feed but no luck

"Why I'm not getting all the posts" - because the site owner might have decided to only put the latest 10 items into their feed ...?

So there is no way to get more ? It's all up to  the website owner ?

Yes, they are generating that feed. So it's their decision, how many items to return. If they don't offer any pagination or date range parameters, either documented somewhere or "guessable" / following any common scheme - then you could only do this by storing posts on your end, the moment you receive them, resp. use some other "aggregator" service, that performs this task for you.
